# vue change event on custom input component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I want to add `@change` event on custom input component.

**This is my component**:

```
<template>
  <div class="w-100">
    <div class="form-text">
      <input
        :value="value"
        @input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="form-text__input"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FormText',
  props: {
    value: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**and this is how I use it**:

```
       <form-text
          v-model="form.placeOfBirth"
        />
```

I want to add `@change` event. This event should fire when user start typing in input, not when data came from API and input were filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the template:

```
    <input
    ...
    @keyup="onKeyUp"
    />
```

in the code:

```
    methods: {
        onKeyUp(event) {
          this.$emit('change', event)
        }
    }
```

Please pay attention that this event will be fired after every pressed key.